# NavigationBar change his color during animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this weird behavior on my navigationBar:
[image: navBar.gif]

And I don't know how to fix it.
My settings on storyboard are:
[image: navBarStoryboard.settings]

I want the bar tint to be .clear so I can have the perfect blur effect.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

try these settings it may help

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isOpaque = true
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 180/255, green: 40/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 180/255, green: 40/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 180/255, green: 40/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Nope... "UIApplication" has no member statusBarView. And as soon as i put my UIColor, it does the same thing.

Comment: It is for just status bar and may be replaced with statusBarStyle. You may ignore it